# Как лучше всего хранить такую структуру в БД

Tags: база-данных, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Имеется сложная структура состоящая из select и radiobutton.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
И база данных данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
В данном примере парковка может не предоставляться или предоставляться платно или бесплатно. В зависимости от выбора (платно/бесплатно/нет) можно указать дополнительные опции (такие как расположение, тип, бронь и т.д.). 
Как лучше всего хранить такую структуру в БД? 
Я вижу решение задачи в виде дерева, не знаю на сколько это верно и не знаю как правильно это реализовать. Если хранить в виде дерева то листами такого дерева будут такие записи: "Платная парковка на территории с необходимостью предварительного резервирования ценой 1000р/д", тогда не понятно как объединить несколько select в один.

Comment: А надо ли так усложнять? Судя по изображению, большинство данных повторяется для разных типов. Вполне можно хранить все в одной таблице.

Comment: NOSQL? По факту, вы его и пытаетесь построить поверх SQL.

Comment: А какая у вас БД?

Comment: Пока использую SQLite (пока учусь) потом на PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте.

Как лучше, решать вам, и поймете вы это со временем.

Я бы начал с простого, примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это как пример, и:
**business** - Бизнес центры
**parking** - Парковки (вообще весь список)
**location** - Расположения (если парковка это ООО, то у нее несколко мест)
**types** - Тип (частная/муник/безхозная - можно и ENUM сделать)
**booking** - Бронирование (способы бронирования)

Платная не платная определяет поле paid (1-платная, 0-нет).
Создаем везде нулевые варианты.
*Если кто подскажет, есть ли другой вариант не создавать нулевые записи, оставив связи, буду признателе.*
Выбираем все бизнес центры и по `LEFT JOIN parking` подрубаем **parking** с `WHERE parking_id>0`.
И если есть запись, то парковка есть, и пошел дальнейший разбор.

Не претендую на **THE BEST**, но сам бы начал с этого.

**UPD1**
Кстати, `location` можно влить в `business`.
С другой стороны не стоит, вдруг парковка через дорогу, а человек добирается по навигатору, то координаты должны быть именно места парковки, а не самого БЦ.

**UPD2**
Нужно еще учесть, что у БЦ может быть несколько парковок.
Поэтому лучше сделать связь *МНОГИЕ-КО-МНОГИМ*: `business <-> parking`.
Извиняюсь, что не сразу, хорошая мысля, приходит апосля...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Дело в том что мне хочется универсальный метод. У отелей много сервисов разных (многие ко многим). Есть такие которые просто предоставляются и все (значит в связующей таблице будет запись "id:1 hotel_id: 10 service_id:120"), а есть такие сервисы которые могут предоставляться платно или бесплатно и при этом иметь свои настройки какие то (как вот парковка). И хотелось бы получить универсальный метод хранения всех сервисов.

Comment: Переименуйте business в otels, а parking в services, не вижу проблемы. В связующей таблицы можно не использовать id, а primery_key сделать  как `otel_id+service_id`

Comment: Добрый день!  А скажите, пожалуйста, каким софтом Вы пользуетесь для отображения взаимосвязей в БД как на скриншоте?

Comment: Мой рисунок сделан с **MySQL Workbench**, у ТС предположительно **phpMyAdmin**

Comment: У меня http://dbdesigner.net/